# Running an SQL Query Along Multiple Databases (same server)

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, search, jakarta-ee

My application uses a multi-tenant database approach where each client has their own database(same database structure).

I'm trying to implement a searching algorithm which would search for specific items in those databases, mostly in two tables. One table containing the item name and the other containing the item attributes, there are around 500+ tenants (for now).

How would I achieve a quick response time for the query, if I were to connect to every single database and run my select query it would take some time I suppose?

What would be the more optimized approach?

SQL Server.
Java EE

Comment: the 2 tables reside in same or different database ?

Comment: Different databases, multiple different databases around 500.

Comment: just use 3 part naming like `FROM DB1.dbo.TBL1 JOIN DB2.dbo.TBL2`

Comment: looping and creating a query with over 500 database's, wouldn't that effect the performance of the query? @Squirrel

Comment: you mean you need to run that query on 500 DB ? or your query involve `JOIN `to 500 DB ?

Comment: maybe you can show us an example of the query that you want to achieve

Comment: There are a couple of points to cover here.  How quick do you need the response time to be?  How fast is your query when run in each database?  Are you providing a UI for the query or do you need to run it against the database.  How frequently is your data updated.  How up-to-date does the data the query runs against need to be?

Comment: @mathewpaxinos Well as fast as possible, around 10 seconds i assume. When running on each database it takes roughly 800 milliseconds. If by UI you mean a specific value being passed to the query yes. Data can be updated by clients (anytime of day), and the search must show the newly updated data to yes, it needs to be very to up date (But i wont mind a 2,3 hour delay even)

Comment: @squirrel I haven't written a query yet, i know how to but i'm just looking for the most optimized approach.